# How to connect two ESP32 via built-in Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, at-commands

I want to connect two ESP32 dev boards via their built-in Bluetooth to share data between them. (e.g. a remote control car and a controller)

I used to connect two HC-05 Bluetooth modules with the help of AT Command. But when it comes to ESP32 built-in Bluetooth module, I cannot find anyway to get into AT mode.

Then I search some ESP32 libraries trying to find some methods with the same function in AT Command, like connecting mode (`AT+CMODE`) and fixed address (`AT+BIND`). But eventually find nothing useful.

So, is it possible to configure that built-in Bluetooth like what AT Command do? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Since I can't comment, because of my reputation, I will write a reply...

Check here in the get started section:
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/esp32/index.html

You can look if your devboard is supported. And then download and flash the appropriate binary.